# Django how can i make inner join

Tags: django, django-queryset

MY models.py

```
class Forms_in_Document(models.Model):

    document_submit = models.ForeignKey(Document_submit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class Document_data(models.Model):

    forms_in_document = models.ForeignKey(Forms_in_Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    document_structure = models.ForeignKey(DocumentStructure , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created= models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(),null=False)
    string = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    integer = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)



class Application(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(),null=False)
    forms_in_document = models.ForeignKey(Forms_in_Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    closed = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
    new = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    media = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    Path_info = models.ForeignKey(Path_info, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
```

The raw SQL query that I am trying to do in Django views.py is

```
Select * from Application app
inner join Document_data dd 
on dd.forms_in_document=app.forms_in_document
```

How can I do the same using Django queryset in my view?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: When using ORMs, it's best to think of the data in terms of objects. Do you necessarily want an inner join, or do you just want to access the documents for each application? If you want the latter, I'll write an answer.

Comment: Hi @GrandPhuba , I want Document_data against each Application. I want to show some columns of Document_data and some columns of Application that belongs to same Forms_in_Document

Comment: I added an answer to your question based on your comment. Let me know if it suffices, and if not, let me know why so I can amend my update

Comment: Hi @GrandPhuba, i really appreciate your effort, You are getting document_data against one application, what i want is to get all document_data and application having common form_in_document  in them

Comment: You just have to get the applications you want, and apply the same code to each application in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Given an `Application` instance, you can access the list of `Document_data` using the following:

```
application = Application.objects.get(...)
documents = applications.forms_in_document.document_data_set.all()
```

#### or

```
application = Application.objects.get(...)
documents = Document_data.objects.filter(forms_in_document__application=application)
```